# Sony VAIO laptop keyboard/touchpad not working after windows update

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

My VAIO (VPCEB46FX) keyboard/touchpad stop working after an unfinished windows update. I was shutting down windows 7, the screen turned off, however, the PC was still running for 30min and not response to any keyboard. So since I didn't see any screen, I thought the OS hanged. So I reset the laptop, after that, the keyboard and touchpad became not working. I have to use USB keyboard/mouse.

There are a lot people reporting same issue after windows update. Since there's no restore point created before the update. So I just restore the laptop to factory setting. However, even doing so still can resolve the issue. When windows 7 is first time starting, I still can't use keyboard/touchpad.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

PS. Before I restored it to factory setting, there's once I found keyboard is working 30min or 1hour after I boot up the machine. I was using USB keyboard/mouse and suddenly just found that the laptop keyboard worked too.

Answer (score 1):

Try <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or whatever keys on your laptop to enable/disable touchpad.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow [these steps](http://handfullknowledge.blogspot.in/2010/12/mouse-pad-not-working-in-ubuntu-1010-on.html):

1. Open the terminal.
2. type the following

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/default/grub
   ```
3. Change the below line to

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
   ```

   to

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="i8042.nopnp"
   ```
4. Save and
5. Type

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
6. Reboot.

Comment: This solution seems to be for Linux, whereas the OP is using Windows.